# Check if node is flagged after webform submit. Rules

Tags: rules, webforms, flags

I have a webform block on a node. I'm trying to send emails to the node (field email) after webform is submitted but only if the current node has been flagged (not the webform). I would presume that rules is the best option for this but cannot get it to work as I cannot access the current node to check?

Emails (webform) should only be sent to the person (node) if they have been verified (flagged).

Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck for a while now.

Comment: Please provide more details about how you implemented that webform block on a node. Doing so may help to get a rules based solution to your question.  What I wonder: how do you know on which node that webform block should be shown?

Comment: Hi Pierre thank you for the response. Webform has an option to set webform as block in advanced settings. The block is displayed on all pages of type node Person. Does that help?

Comment: OK,that helps a bit. How does the path of such nodes (of type Person) look like? Is it just "/node/nid", or any other path that includes the "nid" (=node ID)?

Comment: Hi Pierre, the url is an alias /location/person-name and therefore should still be able to pull the nid?